# Dynamic Array Runtime Error - code working but not for large input values | How to resolve?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, runtime-error, dynamic-arrays

This is the code I wrote and seems like it's working but when I checked on the [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem?isFullScreen=true) for testing with the huge test cases - it's giving me a runtime error.
How can I optimize this code?

```
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    lastAnswer = 0
    seq = []
    result = []
    for k in range(0, n):
        seq.append([])

    for i in queries:
        N_querytype = i[0] #it can be either 1 or 2
        x = i[1]
        y = i[2]
        index = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
        if(N_querytype == 1):
            seq[index].append(y)
        elif(N_querytype == 2):
            lastAnswer = seq[index][y]
            result.append(lastAnswer)
    return result
```

This is the [test-case](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/13642/input00.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1574365595&Signature=dfGAhig18eZXN4iVMyxHifdBKk8%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) for which it is not running. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: your geting an index exception?

Comment: no. just runtime error. But now i understood what i was missing. Thank you for explaining with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer was close but you misunderstood what to do in query 2

Find the value of element `y % size` in `seq` (where `size` is the size of `seq`) and assign it to

So using index you get the sequence which will be a list, but you are then asked to find the value in the list whic his indexed at position `y % size` where `size = len(seq[index])`

```py
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    lastAnswer = 0
    seq = []
    result = []
    for k in range(0, n):
        seq.append([])

    for i in queries:
        N_querytype = i[0] #it can be either 1 or 2
        x = i[1]
        y = i[2]
        index = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
        print("#", index, y)
        if(N_querytype == 1):
            seq[index].append(y)
        elif(N_querytype == 2):
            size = len(seq[index])   #Calculate the size of the sequnce at this index
            lastAnswer = seq[index][y % size] #look up the value in this sequence at index y % size
            result.append(lastAnswer)
    return result
```